# Reading unknown number of words

Tags: c++, string, std

I want to store names that belong to a certain number, and all this in one array. I'm reading from a file that looks like this:

```
1 Alan Ed
2 Eric Sara Lisa Dave
3 Amanda
4 Trevor Juliet Brad
```

I basically want an array of arrays, where I store an array of the names at index 1,2,3,4. How is this done? I'm aware that there are several ways, I'm looking for a simple one.

Comment: Well, it's done by having an array of arrays. What exactly would you like to know?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parse input by `std::getline()` into line strings, parse each line string by `std::strinstream`'s extractors into name strings, use `std::vector<std::string>::push_back()` to append name strings into line entries, gather line entries by another `std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>`.

Something like this, plus-minus syntax errors:

```
vector<vector<string>> result;
istream& is = cin;
while (!is.eof())
{
    string ls;
    getline(is, ls);
    istringstream line_ss(ls);
    result.emplace_back();
    while (line_ss.good())
    {
        string name;
        line_ss >> name;
        result.back().push_back(name);
    }
}
```

P.S. Indexes will be 0,1,2,3. If you *really* need them to be 1,2,3,4, use std::map instead.